# How do I fix SEO urls with lighttpd?

Tags: web, webserver, lighttpd

I want to rewrite my URL from `?p=pagename` to a SEO friendly URL like this: `/pagename`

How does url.rewrite works?

I have seen an example like this but haven't figured how it works yet.

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(data|install|js|styles)/(.*)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.*\.php)(.*)$" => "$0",
    "^/.*(\?.*)" => "/index.php$1",
    "" => "/index.php"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string is not part of the URL matched by rewrite rules.  You can match against the query string separately:

```
    $HTTP["querystring"] =~ "^p=([^&]+)" {
        url.rewrite = (
            "/%1"
        )
    }
```